# How to make speed test with curl?

Tags: php, curl

I want to use fast.com but when I use

```
$curlHandle = curl_init('http://fast.com');
```

it was returned 0. So, Page is not loading.

How can I get speed result with curl?

Comment: You can't check internet speed by an API such as fast, you need to call any API and record the downloaded bytes in a particular time, then calculate the average download time

Answer (score 0):

Some library like this https://github.com/aln-1/speedtest-php might be better suited - it uses speedtest.net.

Just curl-downloading fast.com would only download you the webpage, not perform an actual speed test.

If you want to do it with curl you need to download an actual huge file, for example as found on https://speed.hetzner.de/.

Additionally curl_init does not do the actual transfer - you need to execute it. Read the curl docs for this :-)